# pattern is not working in angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am implementing validations through pattern attribute,it's not working.

```
 <input type="text"  formControlName="mobile" name="mobile" pattern="[0-9]" />
```

Comment: Works fine, but your pattern is `[0-9]`... it should be `[0-9]*` or `[0-9]+`

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. what about email..
        <input type="text"  formControlName="email" name="email" pattern="/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/" />
is there something wrong with regex?

Comment: Yes, the start / end of the regex has `/` which shouldn't be there. Those are only required when writing the regex in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern for mobile number.

```
<input type="text" name="mobile" ng-pattern="/\d{10}/" />
```

Or
you can use this

```
Mobile Number :
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="mobileNo" name="mobileNo" ng-pattern="regEx" />
```

JavaScript

```
$scope.regEx="/^[0-9]{10,10}$/;"
```

If you want to made it work with pattern attribute then

```
<input type="text" pattern="[789][0-9]{9}">
```

Comment: I think u r answering for angular 1, my question was from angular 2, I was not sure whether patterns are supported or not.